# php ignore new line fwrite csv for some characters

Tags: php, csv, fwrite

This is the csv file :

```
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S17C2   1_5_3   8_20_2  8   NA  NA  NA  NA  23:958447298
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S17C2   1_4_3   3_57_2  7   NA  NA  NA  NA  23:958447297
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S17C2   1_1_2   8_20_1  6   NA  NA  NA  NA  23:958447296
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S15C1   1_4_3   7_19_1  0   NA  NA  NA  0   23:958407892
MUM4    7   BHOPA04 BZIV01  NA  S15C2   2_5_3   20_36_0 0   7684    5402    0   23:958426337    3.794444444
MUM5    9   MUMBA15 BUIP04  NA  S15C3   3_2_3   30_38_2 2   7712    10730   1   4.455555556 10:73339
MUM5    15  MUMBA14 BUIP04  NA  S15C1   3_5_1   16_42_0 0   7712    10730   0   23:46542    ***Pending
```

I am trying to get the values from csv after the particular search from the user and fwrite in csv file

```
$f = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$to_write = fopen("sample.csv", "w");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
{
foreach($line as $new)
{ 
if($new!="")
    {
      echo "<td>".$new."</td>";

       $new=str_replace("-","NA",$new);

         if($new == $line[13]) 
         {
          fwrite($to_write,$new.","."\n");
         }
          else 
         {
          fwrite($to_write,$new.",");
         }
    }
}   
}
```

For every 13th column I am writing the line in csv next row, but for the some special values like '0', '-'...for this occurrence from the test.csv file ...

The data is writing in the next line ...

After the complete output writing in the sample.csv file : 
I am getting the output like this :

```
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S17C2   1_5_3   8_20_2  8   NA  NA  NA  NA  23:958447298
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S17C2   1_4_3   3_57_2  -                   
NA  NA  NA  NA  23:958447297                                    
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S17C2   1_1_2   8_20_1  6   NA  NA  NA  NA  23:958447296
KOL2    3   KOLKA05 BLTLA1  NA  S15C1   1_4_3   7_19_1  0                   
NA  NA  NA  0   23:958407892                                    
MUM4    7   BHOPA04 BZIV01  NA  S15C2   2_5_3   20_36_0 0                   
7684    5402    0   23:958426337    3.794444444                                 
MUM5    9   MUMBA15 BUIP04  NA  S15C3   3_2_3   30_38_2 2   7712    10730   1   4.455555556 10:73339
MUM5    15  MUMBA14 BUIP04  NA  S15C1   3_5_1   16_42_0 0                   
7712    10730   0   23:46542    ***Pending
```

I am struggling to figure out why it is happening , For a particular occurrence of the '-','0'....the the file is writing in the next row...how to ignore next line for a particular values like this...

Comment: It's just a wild guess but you can try to `trim($new)` before writing to the file and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope , It won't works ..Is there any other way..

Comment: I don't want to remove the characters, just I want to ignore the new line for the characters like ...'0','-'...

Comment: As a second parameter `trim()` accepts a list of the characters you want trimmed so if I understand correctly what you need you could pass only "\n" as the second argument.

Comment: You should no use `fwrite` to write CSV data without applying any proper handling of special characters – use `fputcsv`.

Comment: If I use , fputcsv() , It is writing the data in row wise in csv file..i want to write in column wise...

Comment: Nope..! ..I added the \n code in trim function..does'nt work...please check

Comment: @CBroe .... have u checked ...fputcsv..its printing only in one column.....want to print column wise in csv...please check

Comment: That makes no sense. You can not write CSV data “column wise” using a serial writing mode. You should built an array that holds your data in the desired form first, and then afterwards write that array into the CSV, row by row.

Comment: @CBroe....K ...but using the fwrite() I can write the data in column wise in csv file.....can you help in the code...building in the new array...and write in the csv file using fputcsv()

Comment: @CBroe...   sorry to ask again ...Is there any way to suppress the characters to avoid the new line for '-','0'...characters..please help